# How do deal with PHP timeout while downloading/zipping images from web

Tags: php, ajax

I've written a short script that takes a user uploaded .csv and downloads images from the web (column A), renames them by a barcode (column B), and then zips those images and downloads it for the user.

The script works fine if the .csv only has 10-100 rows, but the client is wanting to upload a .csv with 1000s of rows and we're now getting server timeout errors (as expected).

I set the max execution time to 0:

`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`

But that didn't do the trick.

The end goal is to simply download all the images and rename them by the barcodes. I thought about maybe splitting the task into multiple chunks of 100 images or so, but even then, I don't know how to get around a server timeout.

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds for a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');` should have done the trick, at least as long as PHP is concerned. Be aware that you may have timeout settings in other layers, such as CGI handler, web server, load balancer...

Comment: The change of max_execution_time from GUI scripts can be prevented by configuration (a measure to protect hosters from users scripts going into a frency...), A connection drop by LB would be a 502 or 504 error code. Long running operations require a queue or another form of async processing.